# c++ what does Derived Default copy constructor initialize Base copy constructor with?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

**Code:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class B{
    public:
    int b;
    B(int x):b(x){
        cout << "B() Constructor " << endl;}
    B(const B& m):b(m.b){
        cout << "B(const B&) copy constructor "<< endl;}
};


class D:public B{
    public:
    D(int x):B(x){
        cout << "D() Constructor " << endl;}
    D(const D& n):B(n){ // at this point n should be casted to B object !!?
        cout << "D(const D&) copy constructor " << endl;}
    operator B(){
        cout << "operator B" << endl;
        return B(this->b);}

};

int main(){

D ob(1);
cout << "---" << endl;
D oc=ob;
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
B() Constructor
D() Constructor
---
B(const B&) copy constructor
D(const D&) copy constructor
```

---

**Questions:** 
1) if I didn't supply my `D` copy constructor, the default copy constructor of `D` must initialize the Base object by calling `B` copy constructor. My question is what is the argument that copy constructor of `B` will take ? is it a `D` object and then it will be casted to a `B` object ?
2) in the copy constructor of `D`, I initialized `B` with a `D` object `n`, and there was no calling to the `operator B()` which proof that the object `n` of type `D` didn't get casted to `B`, so it can be passed as an argument to the `B` copy constructor. is there any explanation for this behavior ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a **cast** is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. There are two categories of conversions: implicit and explicit. Implicit conversions will be done when needed, without a cast. Explicit conversions require a cast. What you're talking about here is an **implicit conversion**, not a cast.

And the answer is that there is an implicit conversion from a reference to a derived type into a reference to a base type. It's that simple: n is a D&, and it can be passed to a function that takes a B& simply by implicitly converting its type.